# Не задаётся пароль для пользователя ROOT в MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux

У меня такая проблема - и на линуксе, и на винде у меня не всегда ставится пароль для root пользователя в MySQL. Не понимаю, в чём проблема.
На линуксе провожу sudo mysql_secure_installation но когда я пытаюсь подключится мне пишет:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Comment: подключиться откуда? можно больше конкретики

Answer (score 1):

Сначала попробуйте авторизоваться от имени root в системе и подключиться

```
mysql
```

Иногда это работает.
В новых версиях ...

`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';`

`SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;`

---

Если не сработало, остановите службу mysql

`systemctl stop mysqld`

`mysqld --skip-grant-tables`

`mysql`

> USE mysql;
>
> UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('ваш_пароль') where USER='root';
>
> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

права над всеми таблицами

`GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

- > перезапустить базу данных и работать .

  `systemctl start mysqld`

версиях после MySQL 5.7.6 (изменения пароля)

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
```

Comment: не помогло :sad_face: